# I need an array or ArrayList that accepts objects of any type

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

I need to create a method in Java that accepts any number of arrays of any type. I need to know if this is possible and if so how?

Comment: What do you mean by any number of arrays?

Comment: Just use `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();` This is the same as `ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();` which accepts any class as input.

Comment: Takes in arrays, and makes them all the length of the longest one. My idea was to take an Array of Object arrays, but I'm not sure that'll work

Comment: You can create a two dimensional ArrayList by making the first List a type of List<Object> like this: `List<List<Object>> myList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Each class is of the type object, so this should do it.

Comment: This worked the best. I will choose it as best when I get home, but for now I must go. Edit: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method that accepts any type of array just like this:

```
public <T> void MyMethod(List<T> mylist){
    System.out.println(mylist);
}
```

Comment: but this works only on generic classes and accepts only list of the class wich T refers.

Comment: I missunderstood his question, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the heading of your question,

Object is superset of all objects. So you can achieve it by creating an array of Object types. You can insert any type into that array.

eg.

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object();
```

To answer your question i.e. to create a method which can accept any number of arrays of any type use variable arguments.

eg.

```
public void method(Object ... params) { <your code>  }  

// This method will accept any number of parameters of any type.
// If it is specific to ArrayLists, use ArrayList<Object> as the parameter type.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Takes in arrays, and makes them all the length of the longest one

ArrayList of arrays is a good way to do it. Arrays.copyOf pads the shorter arrays with null

```
void f(ArrayList<Object[]> list){
        int maxLen = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, list.get(i).length);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            if(list.get(i).length < maxLen)
            list.set(i, Arrays.copyOf(list.get(i), maxLen));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all arrays are objects you can make the method take varargs of Object. Here's how to do literally what you are asked. This could be somewhat simplified if you exclude arrays of primitives (forcing wrapper types like `Integer[]` and `Boolean[]`) so the parameter was `Object[]...`. Then you would not need reflection and the big long if/else block and could return a `List<Object[]>`. In that case the method would be much shorter. Otherwise this kind of thing is very inconvenient.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static List<Object> conform(Object... arrays) {
    ArrayList<Object> out = new ArrayList<Object>(arrays.length);

    int longest = 0;
    for (Object a : arrays) {
        if (!a.getClass().isArray()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(a + " not an array");
        }
        int length = Array.getLength(a);
        if (length > longest) longest = length;
    }

    for (Object a : arrays) {
        if (a instanceof Object[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((Object[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof boolean[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((boolean[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof char[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((char[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof byte[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((byte[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof short[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((short[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof int[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((int[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof long[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((long[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof float[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((float[])a, longest));

        } else if (a instanceof double[]) {
            out.add(Arrays.copyOf((double[])a, longest));
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```